# EE or physics stack exchange - Sensors and interactions the physical world

Tags: discussion

I have a question dealing with IR radiation pickup of a photodiode. There are 2 parts to my question, one which is firmly in the EE realm (question about circuits and component design choice), but the other question is a little iffy.

My question is something along the line of:

> given a blackbody temp of X, what is the leakage current through photodiode D?

Is that still suitable for EE SE or is Physics SE more appropriate?

In general, is there a good "rule of thumb" on what goes on EE SE and what goes on Physics SE as far as sensors and "interfaces" go?

Answer (score 6):

This is still part of an electrical design problem and should fit here, but I have been wrong before.

The real gauge of such an item would be asking a question and seeing if you get an answer here. I hope you do, but I could be wrong. Generally such a leakage would be listed in the datasheet.

Comment: I agree, the Physics SE seems more about particle physics and less applied.  Semiconductor physics is integral to electronics.